# MySQL текущая дата + значение

Tags: mysql, дата, timestamp, default

Можно ли в MySQL создать столбец, в котором дата будет по умолчанию вычисляться как "дата1 + некоторое количество дней"?
Например, у меня есть таблица с полями id, start_date (дата начала), amount_of_days (кол-во дней) и end_date (дата окончания). Дата начала по условию должна быть равна текущей дате, поэтому для неё указан тип timestamp. Дата окончания должна быть: дата начала + кол-во дней. Каким образом можно задать такую формулу вычисления для даты окончания?

```
create table information (id primary key, start_date timestamp not null, amount_of_days int(3) not null, end_date _______);
```

Comment: Т.к. end_date не вносит никакой информации, вам, вероятно, стоит исключить его из схемы. Его можно добавить, например, во view.

Comment: Читайте справку по вычисляемым полям.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться [вычисляемой](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) колонкой:

```
create table information (
    id int not null primary key,
    start_date timestamp not null,
    amount_of_days int(3) not null,
    end_date datetime as (start_date+interval amount_of_days day) virtual
);
```

Comment: Очень похоже на то, что мне нужно! Однако выдаёт ошибку: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as (start_date+interval amount_of_days day) virtual
)' at line 5 Как это можно исправить?

Comment: @GreenTea Установить более новый MySQL. У меня на 5.7.22 данный пример работает. На тесте на версии 5.6 нет. Других решений для более ранних версий, если не делать view, нет

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!